# how to add a unit test for Tableau Embedded Component?

Tags: reactjs, tableau-api, react-testing-library

I would like add a unit test to a simple react(TS) component that embeds a tableau dashboard using the Tableau Javascript API.

An error occurs when I try to run the test file, i get the following error:

[image]

When the page renders, under the `<TableauReport />` an `<iframe />` will be mounted which is generated by Tableau Javascript; see logic under the `useEffect`

Not sure if this is an issue with `react-testing-library`, but I've read also it could be an issue with `jsdom` version; version is `16.7.0`

Here is the component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { server } from '../../constants/tableau'

interface TableauProps {
    options: {
        hideToolbar: boolean,
    };
    view: string;
    ticket?: string;
}

const { tableau }: any = window;

const setVizStyle = {
    width: "800px",
    height: "700px",
  };

const TableauReport = ({ options, view }: TableauProps) => {

    const url = `${server}${view}`

    const tableauRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        new tableau.Viz(tableauRef.current, url, options)
    }, []);
    return (
        <div style={setVizStyle} ref={tableauRef} />
    );
};

export default TableauReport;
```

Here is the test:

```
describe("Tests", () => {

    let windowSpy: any;

    beforeEach(() => {
        windowSpy = jest.spyOn(window, "window", "get");
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        windowSpy.mockRestore();
    })

    const tableauOptions = {
        hideToolbar: true,
    }

    it('should render the component', () => {
        windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => {
            tableau: {
                Viz: jest.fn();
            }
        })
        render(<TableauReport options={tableauOptions} view={dashboard}/>)
    })
});
```

Initially, I had an issue with the `Viz` method in the test, it was not being recognized. I had to add a `spyOn` to then `window` object and mock the implementation.

Is that the right approach to test the `window.tableau`?

I was wondering is there a proper way for testing an embedded tableau dashboard using `react-testing-library`.

Here is the tutorial I followed on how to embed a tableau dashboard using react, [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hc4UCBTACTU&t=2s&ab_channel=AndredeVries)

I'm new to tableau, so any help will be highly appreciated, thanks :)